# ionic 4 android keyboard down left white space

Tags: android, keyboard, whitespace, ionic4, samsung-mobile

In ionic when some stuff is outside ion-content and opens up keyboard then there is a white space shows where the keyboard appear, when keyboard close in the screen.

Answer (score 6):

I found below solution for this -

Find inside platform/android folder

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

You will find it around 3 places and replace it to

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Create new build and enjoy!

Comment: If we use adjustPan, we are unable to scroll over the page.

Comment: In android, this problem was solved. But in ios how to solve this problem?